# How to expand $\tan z$ at $z_{0}= \frac{\pi}{4}$, is it a concise form？

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, taylor-expansion

I want to expand $\tan z$ at $z_{0}=\frac{\pi}{4}$ in taylor series, I try to use $\tan z = \tan[(z-\frac{\pi}{4})+\frac{\pi}{4}]$, it finally becomes:

$$-1+\frac{2}{1-\tan(z-\frac{\pi}{4})}
=-1+2\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(\tan y)^{k}$$

in which $y=z-\frac{\pi}{4}$, but it looks like more complex and difficult.

I hope you can help me. Thank you very much!

Comment: what you do its not a power series

Comment: I want to expand $\tan y$ to the power series on the basis of the above, but it will cause a nested series.

Answer (score 1):

The series expansion you are looking for is of the form:

$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n\left(z-\frac{π}{4}\right)^n$$

with

$$a_n=\frac{f^{(n)}\left(\frac{π}{4}\right)}{n!}\;,$$

where $f^{(n)}\left(\frac{π}{4}\right)$ denotes the n-th derivative of $f(z)=\tan z$ calculated at $z=\frac{π}{4}\;.$

With the above reminder of Taylor series theory you can now write a few terms of the expansion.

Answer (score 0):

The coefficients of the series can be calculated in terms of the Stirling numbers of the second type, or in terms of the Euler's polynomials, look [here](https://oeis.org/A000831) for the explicit formulas

Answer (score 0):

$$\tan(z)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{a_n}{b_n}\left(z-\frac{π}{4}\right)^n$$ where the $a_n$ form sequence $A046982$ in $OEIS$ and $b_n$ form sequence $A046983$

Comment: Could you make it a little less cryptical? I'm not sure that the EOIS = OEIS = Online Encyclopedia of integer sequences acronym is widely known.

Comment: @PierreCarre Maybe it is a typo.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici No need to apologize! I just was not aware of this encyclopedia and had trouble finding it initially. Looking up the sequence's references worked perfectly though.